# Does virtualization add delays on measuring throughput with JMH benchmarks for cpu bound tasks

Tags: java, performance, jmh, throughput

I have a cpu bound task that make some calculation basically its ECDSA verification algorithm that checks if a signature is valid. the code is working pretty well. What i am trying to do now is to measure the actual throughput so I use the `JMH` and this method

```
 @Benchmark
    @Threads(16)
    @Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-XX:+UseZGC"})
    public static void ECDSA() {
        boolean verify = ecdsaSign.secp256Verify(hash, ecKeyPair.getPublicKey(), signatureData);
        assertEquals(verify, true);
    }
```

i am using `windows 10` and this is my cpu
1`2th Gen Intel Core i9-12900K` with `16` cores

The results are pretty interesting and are the following

```
# JMH version: 1.34
# VM version: JDK 11.0.15, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.15+10-jvmci-22.1-b06
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\graalvm-ce-java11-22.1.0\bin\java.exe
# VM options: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCIProduct -XX:-UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dvisualvm.id=26191149540700 -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51600:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseZGC
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint (auto-detected, use -Djmh.blackhole.autoDetect=false to disable)
# Warmup: 1 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 1 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 16 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: io.Adrestus.crypto.ECKeyPaiMeasurementsTest.ECDSA

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:20
# Fork: N/A, test runs in the host VM
# *** WARNING: Non-forked runs may silently omit JVM options, mess up profilers, disable compiler hints, etc. ***
# *** WARNING: Use non-forked runs only for debugging purposes, not for actual performance runs. ***
# Warmup Iteration   1: 111686.397 ops/s
Iteration   1: 116206.227 ops/s

Result "io.Adrestus.crypto.ECKeyPaiMeasurementsTest.ECDSA":
  116206.227 ops/s


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:21

REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights, you need to follow up on
why the numbers are the way they are. Use profilers (see -prof, -lprof), design factorial
experiments, perform baseline and negative tests that provide experimental control, make sure
the benchmarking environment is safe on JVM/OS/HW level, ask for reviews from the domain experts.
Do not assume the numbers tell you what you want them to tell.

Benchmark                                        Mode  Cnt       Score   Error  Units
ECKeyPaiMeasurementsTest.ECDSA  thrpt       116206.227          ops/s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

around **120k** ops/s

My problem now is that when I tried to measure the same code from an ubuntu virtual machine with vmware the results are so much different. The performance is x3 slower. Why does this happen? is it the overhead latency from virtualization? do i did something wrong?

These is the results from Ubuntu-Vmware
(p.s i gave the same number of cores on my vmware)

```
# JMH version: 1.34
# VM version: JDK 11.0.16, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.16+8-jvmci-22.2-b06
# VM invoker: /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java11-22.2.0/bin/java
# VM options: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCIProduct -XX:-UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/387/lib/idea_rt.jar=40785:/snap/intellij-idea-community/387/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseZGC
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint (auto-detected, use -Djmh.blackhole.autoDetect=false to disable)
# Warmup: 1 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 1 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 16 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: io.Adrestus.crypto.ECKeyPaiMeasurementsTest.ECDSA

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:20
# Fork: N/A, test runs in the host VM
# *** WARNING: Non-forked runs may silently omit JVM options, mess up profilers, disable compiler hints, etc. ***
# *** WARNING: Use non-forked runs only for debugging purposes, not for actual performance runs. ***
# Warmup Iteration   1: 33379.533 ops/s
Iteration   1: 36017.192 ops/s

Result "io.Adrestus.crypto.ECKeyPaiMeasurementsTest.ECDSA":
  36017.192 ops/s


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:20

REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights, you need to follow up on
why the numbers are the way they are. Use profilers (see -prof, -lprof), design factorial
experiments, perform baseline and negative tests that provide experimental control, make sure
the benchmarking environment is safe on JVM/OS/HW level, ask for reviews from the domain experts.
Do not assume the numbers tell you what you want them to tell.

Benchmark                                        Mode  Cnt      Score   Error  Units
Adrestus.crypto.ECKeyPaiMeasurementsTest.ECDSA  thrpt       36017.192          ops/s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the cpu profiler of the windows machine
[image]
This is the cpu profiler of the ubuntu machine
[image]
Maybe the info of the cpu profiler are helpful

What is the problem here?Is any way to achieve similar results or is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

In general virtualization of course costs something and probably your assumption is correct, however personally I see some things that can be fixed here. Having them fixed let's redo the experiment and compare the numbers again.

First of all, benchmark is not a test - you should rather return `boolean` value from your benchmark method instead of doing assertion. Assuming we already know the calculation is correct I'd rewrite the code as:

```java
@Benchmark
@Threads(16)
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-XX:+UseZGC"})
public boolean ECDSA() {
  return ecdsaSign.secp256Verify(hash, ecKeyPair.getPublicKey(), signatureData);
}
```

Second, you run the benchmar in 16 threads, but from the screenshots I see that on Windows you have 15 workers and only 12 on Ubuntu. Please double check whether you have the same number of threads everywhere.

Third, it looks like you are running your benchmark from IDEA. In general this approach is not wrong, however it's more correct to run the benchmark from command line, e.g. `user@mymachine:~/IdeaProjects/your-jmh-project$java -jar target/benchmarks.jar ...`. In this particular case IDEA is a Java application run on the same machine as the benchmark, so when you specify 16 threads (same as number of cores of the CPU) you must understand, that in practise some of JMH workers could be competing with other threads for CPU cores and other workers could monopolize their cores. In addition you have OS utilizing the same cores and the number of OS threads is likely to be different for Windows and Linux. Let's  try to reduce the number of JMH threads, e.g. by using `@Threads(4)`.

Fourth, as of your output it looks like forked VMs peek up options from command line: `# VM options: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCIProduct -XX:-UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dvisualvm.id=26191149540700 -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51600:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseZGC` 
I'd double check whether you actually need them (apart from `-XX:+UseZGC`).